# Translation-golf XX - Calvin's Ethics about life

Tags: traducción, translation-golf

¡Bienvenidos de nuevo al Translation Golf!
Para quienes empiezan, en la parte inferior encuentran la información relacionada...

En esta ocasión, decidí invocar a todo un filósofo que intenta solucionar los problemas del mundo. Me refiero al gran Calvin, de Calvin & Hobbes. En esta ocasión, de la interesante charla con su amigo, hemos de traducir el monólogo de Calvin.

Aquí vamos: (con 646 caracteres, cada párrafo es un cuadro de la caricatura)

> Today at school, I try to decide whether to cheat on my test or not.
>
> I wondered, is it better to do the right things and fail... or is it better to do the wrong things and succeed?
>
> On the one hand, undeserved success gives no satisfaction. ...But on the other hand, well-deserved failure gives no satisfaction either
>
> Of course, most everybody cheats sometime or other. People always bend rules if they think they can get away with it. Then again, that doesn't justify my cheating
>
> Then I thought, look, cheating in one little test isn't such a big deal. It doesn't hurt anyone. ...But then I wondered if i was just rationalizing my unwillingness to accept the consequence of no studying.
>
> Still, in the real world, people care about success not principles ...Then again, maybe that's why the world is in such a mess. What a dilemmma! (...)

Una adaptación de la caricatura traducida es: (529 caracteres)

> -Hoy en la escuela no sabía si hacer trampa en mi prueba o no
>  -¿No sé si es mejor hacer lo correcto y fallar... o es mejor hacer trampa y triunfar?
>  -Por una parte, un éxito no merecido no satisface, por otra parte, el fracaso merecido tampoco
>  -La mayoría hace trampa alguna vez. La gente siempre modifica las reglas si piensa que se puede zafar. Otra vez, eso no justifica que yo haga trampa.
>  -Luego me dije, trampear en una pequeña prueba no es nada grave, no daña a nadie... Pero luego no sé si estoy justificando las consecuencias por no estudiar
>  -En el mundo real, a la gente lo que le interesa es el éxito, no los principios. De nuevo, quizás por eso el mundo es un lío. ¡vaya dilema! (...)

Para quien desee leerla toda, [aquí](http://www.gocomics.com/calvinandhobbes/2013/9/15) está disponible.

Éxitos a todos y a lucirse planteando la mejor traducción con menos caracteres.

- Recordatorio de las normas: [Translation-golf rules](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2592/5481)
- Link para contar caracteres: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ermv0rh/2/embedded/result/)

Para debatir temas relacionados con el juego hay una sala de chat: [Translation Golf!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66153/translation-golf)

Felicitaciones a todos por aportar sus ideas en traducir y más que todo para @blonfu por su traducción de 147 caracteres. Tienes 48 horas para presentar un texto, después de lo cual, queda en libertad de cualquier usuario la presentación de texto a la edición XXI.

Comment: Cada vez los textos son más largos :$. Por otra parte me gustan mucho las historietas de Calvin y Hobbes, buena elección.

Comment: Llévate otro +1 de mi parte para que te animes a seguir participando en el sitio. Me da que este texto va a ser bastante _golfeable_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### <s>280 191 161</s> 147 caracteres

> ¿Digno [cate](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7vkqNww) o aprobado [vil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bobcqY3)? No molan.
>
> Sin [pena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SQbVLbD%7CSQczESN) no hay reglas, mas no es excusa.
>
> Trampas en examen nimio no dañan. No estudié y busco razones.
>
> El éxito manda, no los ideales, una [liada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NDhqOIi). ¡Qué duda!

Junto las tres primeras frases en una sola. Uso *cate* y *aprobado* para dar a entender que se habla de un examen. Al decir que el cate (suspenso) es digno y el aprobado vil (indigno) se sobreentiende que para aprobar se ha hecho alguna trampa.

Comment: olvidaste el motivo de todo el discurso, la oración inicial *Today at school, I try to decide whether to cheat on my test or not.*

Comment: La idea de usar aprobar y suspender era dar por supuesto que hablaba del un examen y la palabra cate se usa sobre todo para el ámbito eacolar.

Answer (score 5):

## <del>269</del> <del>267</del> <del>265</del> <del>230</del> <del>228</del> <del>225</del> <del>197</del> 195 caracteres

> Hoy intenté decidir trampear o no en mi examen.
>
> Pesé la pregunta: éxito injusto o el revés: no satisfacen. Gente no vista trampea. ¿Quizás no justifique aún la minucia de tapar mi pereza?
>
> Por fin cuenta el éxito... ¿Lo que explica el mundo? ¡Qué dilema!

1. Un poco más cerca de ser español
2. Un poco más cerca de ser el texto de origen
3. Preguntarse cuál es lo mejor -> pesar la pregunta (segunda definición [http://dle.rae.es/?id=SmGC3aC|SmGsWXw](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SmGC3aC%7CSmGsWXw)); Meritado -> merecido; ...el acto: el de hacer x... -> ...el acto: hacer x...

Como siempre, si hay fallos de Español, quiero saberlo.

Comment: Tengo mi GBoard puesto en superposición FI-FR-ES... No debería confiar tanto en tecnología. Gracias

Comment: Bien visto. Lo he corrido.

Comment: vas bastante bien y puedes seguir mejorando. En particular, no es muy legible la frase * tan pequeño que sea el acto: cubrir mi pereza.* basta con cambiar 2 palabras, pero más no te puedo ayudar.

Comment: En ese contexto, en vez de "el revés", es "al revés".
Y "gente no vista trampea" me suena un poco... [macarrónico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NlfD87k)... Me parece una construcción muy muy rebuscada, al borde de la incorrección.

Comment: en cuanto a lo que menciona @Alicia, (espero no perderte con gramática) esa frase suena mejor como Sujeto - Verbo - Objeto, corrigiendo el objeto "no vista " (Mörkö es finés, lo que causa algunas frases macarrónicas)

Comment: @Mörkö Ya que terminamos, es mejor: "La gente trampea sin ser vista" que "Gente no vista trampea". Para disminuir caracteres tendrías que usar sinónimos de "sin ser vista"

Answer (score 5):

## <strike>179</strike> <strike>173</strike> 172 caracteres

> Hoy en el cole pensé en copiar...
>
> ¿Fracaso justo o éxito injusto?
>
> Ninguna opción mola.
>
> Todos engañan si pueden zafarse... Eso no me exime.
>
> Por una vez... ¿O son excusas de vago?
>
> En realidad, solo queremos éxito; así va el mundo. ¡Uf!

Comment: no te comprendo el cunde, para rematar ni la RAE ni la  ASALE colaboran con sus diccionarios

Comment: Cierto que no figura en la RAE exactamente así, pero yo lo uso como en el sentido figurado de las acepciones 3 ó 4... Sería algo así como que algo te resulta útil o provechoso, que te "mola". Quizás sea argot de España o de mi zona. Si no te convence, busco otro sinónimo.

Comment: Prefiero un sinónimo, si bien @blonfu manifiesta que es término usual en España, la regla es que los vocablos deben estar en el DLE o el Diccionario de americanísmos y aunque está el término, las acepciones no son las adecuadas

Answer (score 4):

### <strike>357 278 237 199 163</strike> 152 caracteres

> ¿Uso [chuleta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9330GZD)? ¿Éxito fácil o [chasco](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8eKvbET) duro? Ninguno [mola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PY9Zg13). Oculto es fácil copiar, mas no me [salva](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X8aav2k). "[Da igual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KwNhWlf#Cd91H1p), no hace daño": ¿mero [velo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bUwgYjN) de mi [flojera](http://dle.rae.es/?id=I6M0eyb)? Mas se [mira](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PMSRG3d) el éxito, no el [ideario](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KtbYMfR): así va todo. ¡Dilem[ón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=R3Ff5cR)!

Explicaciones:

- Evito todos los "I wondered", "I thought", ya que se nota claramente que el texto son los pensamientos de Calvin.
- Elimino las coletillas innecesarias como "on the other hand", "of course", etc.
- Las chuletas se usan en los exámenes. Dado que el que habla es un niño, se entiende que se debate entre si usar chuletas en el colegio o no.
- Presente prospectivo en "¿uso chuleta?", con el verbo en presente indicando una acción a ocurrir en el futuro inmediato.
- Decididamente, las primeras frases vienen a decir lo mismo. "Hacer bien el mal" equivale a "tener éxito fácil", y "hacer mal el bien" equivale al fracaso aun habiendo tomado la vía difícil. Por tanto, se fusionan ambas frases en una.
- "Oculto es fácil copiar": si se copia se entiende que se están quebrantando las normas, y si es fácil se entiende que la gente caiga habitualmente en dicha trampa alguna vez.
- "Da igual", se entiende que habla de que "copiar" da igual, no importa.
- "Velo" (acepción 8): Pretexto, disimulación o excusa con que se intenta ocultar, atenuar u oscurecer la verdad.
- "Mirar" (acepción 9): Cuidar, atender, proteger, amparar o defender a alguien o algo.
- Cuando te quejas de que "así va todo" o de que "así va el mundo", se entiende que te quejas porque va mal.

Answer (score 4):

#### <strike>281</strike> 179

> Copiar en el cole...
>   ¿Ser bueno? Lícita caída. ¿Malo? Amargo éxito. Nada gusta.
>   Todos mienten si cuela. ¿Y a mi qué?
>   Por una no pasa nada... ¿O solo rehúso catear por no estudiar?
>   En el mundo, "el fin justifica los medios". ¿Por eso va así? ¡Qué duda!

<sub>No he leído las otras entradas, solo el conteo. Si he usado algo de otro participante, comentario y veo de cambiarlo.

OP, si algo no te cuadra, comentario y lo explico.</sub>

Comment: no me suena mucho (quizá no me es familiar) el "ser base" como sinónimo de justificar (creo que lo usas en ese sentido). Sería mejor si podés facilitar un ejemplo.

Comment: ok, ya te capto la idea.

Answer (score 2):

Una entrada casi fuera de concurso, que lo importante es participar :-)

## 452 caracteres

> Hoy en clase intenté decidir si copiar o no en el test
>
> Pregunta: es mejor fallar con lo correcto o triunfar con lo reprobable?
>
> Por un lado, el éxito no merecido no satisface. Por el otro el fracaso merecido no gratifica.
>
> Todo el mundo hace trampa alguna vez, saltándose las reglas si pueden, pero eso no me justifica.
>
> Pensé que copiar solo en este examen no era para tanto ni hace daño a nadie, pero solo racionalizaba mi rechazo a las consecuencias de no estudiar.
>
> En el mundo real, priman los resultados,  no los principios. Quizá por eso el mundo es un lío. Qué dilema!